# Timestamp columns in Peer to Peer Replication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, replication

According to MSDN post https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151196(v=sql.105).aspx Timestamp columnns are restricted in Peer to Peer replication.
Does this mean that we can't use Timestamp columns in database that we are going to replicate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested it myself.
*TimeStamp* columns are not allowed. You can't replicate a table if it contains a *TimeStamp* column.

I got the following message when I tried:

> The table cannot be published because it contains a timestamp column. Timestamp columns are not supported in Peer-to-Peer publication.

[image]