# Alternate of TimeStamp for row versioning and Peer to Peer Replication

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

**Scenario:** As per our [findings](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/167470/timestamp-columns-in-peer-to-peer-replication) the table cannot be used in peer to peer replication if it contains column with datatype `timestamp`.

MSDN:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151196(v=sql.105).aspx

**Err:**
[image]

We are using timestamp columns for row versioning in almost every table that need to be replicated.

**Question**:
For peer to peer replication case, is there any alternate of timestamp column  ?

*Note: [Rowversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql) datatype reacts same as timestamp.*